# { user_id } is incrementing when im requesting an access token in Instagram Basic Display API using Insomnia and Axios

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, nestjs, instagram-api, insomnia

Im sending "POST" request to https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token to obtain an access token in order to fetch instagram user basic info. But I notice when im calling the api above using exact same credential but different way then the { user_id } from the response object is incrementing. Why is that?

**FIRST WAY IS USING INSOMIA**:

> > Notice the **user_id** ends with *****499**
> > [image]

**SECOND WAY IS USING AXIOS INSIDE NEST JS SERVICE AND CALLING THE ENDOINT USING INSOMIA**:

> > Notice the **user_id** is **incremented by 1**.
> > [image]

[image]

The worst thing is the **user_id** that ends with *****500** is not valid. (See the error below)
[image]

Why is that happened? Weird...

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I am guessing you are having a problem with user ids getting treated as numbers - with integer overflows & float inaccuracies, you can easily get this kind of "discrepancy."

Comment: Yes, I found that the id its actually ***499 but when it converts to number it was round of to ***500. But why on my first way is not incrementing?

Comment: Probably gets treated as an integer value when Axios automatically parses the received JSON.

Comment: so what i did is, before returning the ***500 I reduce by 1 and returned it as a string to prevent rounding of, however this is just an temporary fix. Do you have better solution than this? Feel free to answer it :).

Comment: Reducing by 1 does not sound like a good idea at all. You will most likely not get this effect for _all_ IDs the API will return, but only some.

Comment: i agree, can you suggest better and permanent solution? I just did that to continue task for one id user.

I totally agree. So the issue is from the response is actually a number. if i return and transform it to string then its already ***500 instead of ***499.

Comment: I am not sure at which point this actually goes wrong, from your screenshots it looks like the API might not be returning this as a string value to begin with? In that case, I'd consider that a bug with the IG API, and it should be reported as such. (Facebook explicitly returns user ids as string values within the realm of the normal Graph API, but it could be the IG API is behaving differently.)

Comment: I totally agree... Because when I call directly from the graph api then, it returns number and not string. that is why axios received it from the response as a "number". then perhaps axios do a parseInt(string) behind the hood. Because the result of expression => parseInt(**************499) =  **************500.